# Simple jQuery AJAX question

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a menu like this, but the mark-up doesn't have to stay this way.

```
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#item1">Item 1</a></li>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#subitem1">Subitem 1</a></li>
   </ul>
  <li><a href="#item2">Item 2</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And each time one of these menu items is clicked I want to load different content in a div - let's call it #content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu li').click(function(){
      $('#content').load('content.txt');
  });
});
```

Now, how do I pass which content page I want to load into #content? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reinventing frames, using JavaScript. All the drawbacks with the added bonus of search engine invisibility.

Comment: That's a good point but this isn't for a critical application, just trying to familiarize myself with AJAX in jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent the click from going to the page with the event's preventDefault() method, use the link's href that actually goes to that page loaded into the #content div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu a').click(function(e){
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});


<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="page1.html">Item 1</a></li>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="subpage1.html">Subitem 1</a></li>
   </ul>
  <li><a href="page2.html">Item 2</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is it better than the method using rel?

Comment: I like it because it's less code but is there another reason that makes it better?

Comment: semantically, it's better, and search engine crawlers follow the href attribute in links. Also, when users have javascript disabled, they will simply be directed to the page rather than having it AJAX'd.

Comment: Ah, hadn't thought of that. So this takes care of the visibility issue quite nicely then.

Comment: Combining this with ToonMariner's suggestion should make it so that you can have a page that degrades perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in numerous ways. Essentially, you need to associate a URL with each `<li>` item.

To name a few ways, you could have them stored in a JavaScript array, in the jQuery cache i.e. `$(selector).data`, in a hidden input inside each `<li>` element, as an attribute on the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like [jQuery UI's tab feature](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) to handle this.  It will probably degrade better.

If you need to do this manually, your easiest route may be to add an ID or rel attribute to the anchors, and then use that to determine the content page you want to load.

You can use "$(this).attr('blah');" within your function to access these properties.

Comment: Do you know if the contents of the tabs are invisible to search engines as well?

Comment: You can do the tabs in a way that when clicked (if js is not enabled) it loads the entire page again, with the chosen tab selected.  This allows search engines to crawl the tabs as well.

Answer (score 1):

in the realms of progressive enhancement - you should make the links point to another page with their respective content.

then you can load not just the entire contents of the page into your content div but a specified element.  So if its the contents of the #content div in the other page is required something like:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(){
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content');
});
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

only problem with joelpittets solution is that it would load the ENTIRE contents of the other page which may not be what is desired. He did however remember to cancel the default behaviour  of clicking a link...

Comment: Yes, combining that with your answer makes it work great in a lot of other scenarios, but for my purposes I'm just loading random text files.